# Event sourcing authentication remeber_me token best practices

Tags: event-sourcing

I have a system that uses event sourcing.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#remembering-users

I'm trying to replicate the functions of the basic Laravel authentication. However with event sourcing the remember me token seems a little strange to add the event stream.

In the normal functionality its stored in the database. In an event souring system where should this be stored? In the event stream as an event. `UserRememberMeLoginRequest`.

My issue here is that these events could be very frequent. leading to a stream that mostly just updates on that one field of the aggregate.

Upon user creation an event is stored in an aggregate `user-created`. After which when logging in I need to store this remember_me token. Whats the best way to do this?

EDIT:
Would it be right to insert into a table from somewhere other than a projector?

Comment: How do you check the validity of a password at login? Do you have to replay the "user" event stream from the beginning of time to find out if the user trying to login is registered and if they are using their current password? Or did you have something else in mind? The `remember_me` token is not all that different from a frequently changing password.

Comment: Yes it would have to use the aggregate for any WRITE actions. But not to repeat the docs. I can use snapshot.

Comment: I can't see a pref hit there. Perhaps i'm wrong. Its pick the stream by index. and then enumerates the length since the last snapshot. At something like 50 events per snapshot. Its going to be quite fast I assume compared to log n (in btree) where n is records for all users.

Comment: But my concern is that in a User aggregate, with events per SESSION. Perhaps multiple sessions per USER. Its going to be adding lots of events. Would it be right to insert into a table from somewhere other than a projector? With that table not really being a projection.

Comment: Maybe reverse this, why do you need a single session aggregate? Does anything other than your authentication system even need to know about the remember me? Have you considered using a remember me token that implicitly validatable without being stored?

Comment: @user1937198 How could one revoke such a token. Laravel removes the remember_token by overriding it when authenticating a session. What where you thinking? it sounds awesome. Yes It could have perhaps it as a token that gets refreshed by the frontend while its open. but then as far as i'm aware I would need to store this in memory to send it to the application which violates the secure cookie https standbox. Similar to using oauth?

Comment: It should be said that this is a simple MVC application.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Yes it would have to replay the event stream to authenticate a client. Well in Laravel, the projection could work as everything is synchronous. But I don't think that scales once things become async

Comment: Keep an event stream of revoked tokens. Since revokng is inherently less frequent that generation, and only revocations within the token lifetime are relevant, this is much easier to keep track of. As for how to implement this, a JWT can be sent to the client, whilst still maintaining the integrity and authenticity properties necessary for this role if the certificate is provided to the server.

Comment: ohh :0 :) thanks. Thats perfect. I'll take a look